# WOPI Host implementation, trying to render doc in iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I'm trying to get Wopi host implementation in Ruby on Rails application.

My domain is whitelisted under CSPP. Trying to get the file contents in iframe, but I just see "Word Online" and a loading gif, I return binary file contents of docx as response to `..wopi/files/:id/contents`. I don't get any calls hitting my host server.

Sample wopi_src_url: `https://word-view.officeapps-df.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?ui=1033&rs=1033&dchat=false&IsLicensedUser=0&WOPISrc=https://sgdevwopi.test-wopi.sycamoreinformatics.com/wopi/files/31/contents?access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2&access_token_ttl=160000000`

[image]

Able to get the Wopi validation page in Iframe using `.wopitest` file. How should I proceed further? Or what am I missing? Please help.

**Note:** I'm using ngrok to make my local app server visible publicly with whitelisted domain.

Comment: Hi, can you please help me in clearing some doughts in wopi protocol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see to problems with your URL. You must ensure that

- the URL is of the form `http://server/<...>/wopi/files/(file_id)` (so drop the `/contents` part - WOPI client will call the `/contents` endpoint automatically when necessary)
- the WOPISrc parameter value is encoded to a URL-safe string

More info [here](https://wopirest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/concepts.html#term-wopisrc) and [here](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/discovery.html#appending-wopisrc).

Comment: Thanks @rocky it worked!! :) Able to view docx files now.

Comment: @rocky check this same issue but using .net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585168/wopi-host-implementation-trying-to-render-doc-in-iframe-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I will, in a few days

Comment: @rocky do you mean no need to use the /contents endPoint in the host page? what about other endPoints like lock PUT etc .. ?

Comment: You have to implement at least the [GET /contents endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/getfile#getfile) on the WOPI host side. However, you shouldn't put `/contents` in the host pages's source URL. Locks are required only for editing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/cloud-storage-partner-program/rest/files/lock